# Java & Hibernate (mysql) console: to many coonections

Tags: java, android, mysql, hibernate

I have created a Java server where I implement a database with hibernate. The client is an android application. When I test the client I can receive this message on my java console:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
 at server.ClientInS.fArticoli(ClientInS.java:303)
 at server.ClientInS.ramifica(ClientInS.java:123)
 at server.ClientInS.run(ClientInS.java:86)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
 ... 17 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1112)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2508)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor72.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
 ... 32 more
```

currently the idea that I have done, is that for one reason or another there are too many users trying to work within the db.

I have checked the code to be sure there are no problems such as client left pending or thread out of control.

I hope someone is able to decipher the meaning behind these report.

Comment: Are you familiar with databases? You know how to use a connection pool etc.?

Comment: I'm not workin on db, hibernate have it. connection.pool_size was 300 (hibernate.cfg.xml) The fact is only by launching an application, I reaching this problem, is strange.

Comment: You're still working with a database even if you have Hibernate on top of it. That's also a way too large size for a connection pool.